# Crash when subclassing UIToolbar

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitoolbar

I have subclassed the UIToolbar to make it easier to implement a safari next, previous, done sort of thing.
It all worked fine when i was adding it directly (ie not subclassing) but now that i am, it crashes every time i click one of the buttons with 
`-[keyboardToolBar hideKeyboard:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance`
This is the first time i have attempted to subclass something so im not sure if i have done something the wrong way.

Code for the subclass

```
@interface keyboardToolBar : UIToolbar {
UIToolbar *keyboard;
UIBarItem *previous;
UIBarItem *next;
UIBarItem *done;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) UIToolbar *keyboard;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIBarItem *previous;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIBarItem *next;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIBarItem *done;

-(void)previousField;
-(void)nextField;
-(void)hideKeyboard;


@end


#import "keyboardToolBar.h"


@implementation keyboardToolBar
@synthesize keyboard, previous, done, next;

-(UIToolbar*)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame{
//Create a new toolbar
keyboard = [[UIToolbar alloc]initWithFrame:frame];

//Create all the buttons and point them to methods
UIBarButtonItem *previousButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Previous" 
                                                            style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered 
                                                            target:self 
                                                            action:@selector(previousField:)];
UIBarButtonItem *nextButton     = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Next" 
                                                            style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered 
                                                            target:self 
                                                            action:@selector(nextField:)];
UIBarButtonItem *filler     = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace 
                                                            target:nil 
                                                            action:nil];
UIBarButtonItem *doneButton     = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Done" 
                                                            style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered 
                                                            target:self 
                                                            action:@selector(hideKeyboard:)];

//Set the width of both of the buttons to make it look pritty
previousButton.width = 70.0f;
nextButton.width = 70.0f;

self.previous = previousButton;
self.next = nextButton;
self.done = doneButton;

//Add the buttons to the toolbar
[keyboard setItems:[[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:self.previous, self.next, filler, self.done, nil] autorelease]];


//Release the buttons
[previous release];
[next release];
[filler release];
[done release];


//return the shiny new toolbar
return keyboard;
}

-(void)previousField{

}

-(void)nextField{

}

-(void)hideKeyboard{
NSLog(@"hello");
}


@end
```

and is called using `UIToolbar *keyboard = [[keyboardToolBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.bounds.size.width, 50)];`

I have tried everything i can think of but still get the same error. Im sure i am just not retaining something somewhere of pointing the buttons to the wrong place but any help would be muchly appreciated
Thanks
Darc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You (or something you're doing) is calling `hideKeyboard:` (note the colon, indicating that the method has one argument.). However, the `hideKeyboard` method you've implemented, doesn't take any arguments.

Most likely, `hideKeyboard` should be changed to:

```
- (void)hideKeyboard:(id)sender {
   NSLog(@"hello");
}
```

As an aside, the usual style for class names is capitalized, so your subclass should be `KeyboardToolBar` (and I'd also recommend keeping the same camel case as Apple's classes, so `KeyboardToolbar` would be best).

Comment: Dam it, new it would be something simple. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that your buttons are calling functions that take an input, but your functions do not take an input:

```
UIBarButtonItem *doneButton     = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Done" 
                                                            style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered 
                                                            target:self 
                                                            action:@selector(hideKeyboard:)];
```

This means that there must be a method `hideKeyboard:(id)sender`. But you have

```
-(void)hideKeyboard{
NSLog(@"hello");
}
```

Either add the input to the function or remove the `:` from the selector call.

Answer (score 1):

you effectively wrote it as a class method, here is a little bit better version, because of memory management issues etc.

-(UIToolbar*)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame{
    //Create a new toolbar

```
if ((self = [super initWithFrame:frame]))


//Create all the buttons and point them to methods
previous = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Previous"  style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self  action:@selector(previousField:)];

next  = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Next" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered  target:self  action:@selector(nextField:)];
UIBarButtonItem *filler     = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace  target:nil  action:nil];
done     = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Done"  style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(hideKeyboard:)];

//Set the width of both of the buttons to make it look pritty
previous.width = 70.0f;
next.width = 70.0f;

//Add the buttons to the toolbar
[keyboard setItems:[[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:previous, next, filler, done, nil] autorelease]];


//Release the buttons
[previous release];
[next release];
[filler release];
[done release];


//return the shiny new toolbar
return self;
}
```

also fix your methods to be either
`@selector(someAction)` to match `-(void)someAction;`
or `@selector(someAction:)` to match `-(void)someAction:(id)sender;`

also no reason to keep a reference to UIToolBar * keyboard, because you want that to be self.
actually probably no reason to keep references to the buttons at all unless you will need to change their titles or action/target pairs later.

Comment: Not quite: The original code returns a UIToolbar instead of a keyboardToolBar (almost certainly wrong) and leaks the keyboardToolBar  that is receiving efents!